# Como obter o CEP completo utilizando reverseGeocodeLocation no xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, código-postal

Estou utilizando o `reverseGeocodeLocation` para buscar o CEP e ele funciona bem; no entanto, traz apenas 5 dígitos do CEP. Como conseguir o CEP completo? Segue o código:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coords = newLocation.coordinate;

    lastLat = coords.latitude;
    lastLng = coords.longitude;

    CLGeocoder *reverse = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:coords.latitude       longitude:coords.longitude];
    lastAccuracy = newLocation.horizontalAccuracy;
    lblAccuracy.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",lastAccuracy];
    if(lastAccuracy<=10)
    {
    [reverse reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if ([placemarks count]>0) {
            CLPlacemark *place = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            strCEP = place.postalCode;
            strLastSubLocation = place.subLocality;
            strLastLocation = place.locality;
            strEndereco = place.thoroughfare;
            lblEndereco.text = strEndereco;
            strLastLocation = [strLastLocation stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Saõ" withString:@"São"];
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Além das propriedades discretas, a classe `CLPlacemark` define um dicionário contendo o endereço conforme as chaves definidas pelo framework AddressBook. Para inspecionar o dicionário, insira a linha abaixo logo após obter o `place`:

```
NSLog(@"Address dictionary: %@", place.addressDictionary);
```

Você verá que há uma chave chamada `PostCodeExtension` que, quando existir, contém os três dígitos adicionais do CEP. O valor é do tipo `NSString`, então você pode concatená-lo ao `place.postalCode`. Para obter essa extensão, você pode escrever algo como

```
NSString *strExtensaoCEP = place.addressDictionary[@"PostCodeExtension"];
```

ou

```
NSString *strExtensaoCEP = [place.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"PostCodeExtension"];
```

Há um porém: na [referência de ABPerson](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Address_Property), não há uma constante para `PostCodeExtension`. No caso do CEP, por exemplo, há a constante `kABPersonAddressZIPKey`. Talvez isto signifique que não haja suporte formal para essa constante e, por exemplo, ela possa deixar de existir em versões futuras. Internamente, [o framework GeoServices contém uma propriedade chamada `postCodeExtension`](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GEOStructuredAddress.h#L24), então *talvez* esse já seja um campo estável. Pode também ser o caso de que haja planos de criar uma constante ou que eles apenas tenham se esquecido dela. Sugiro que você abra um radar solicitando uma constante equivalente e escreva seu código tendo em mente que essa chave pode ser renomeada ou deixar de existir.

Comment: Olá Amigo! Perfeito! Funcionou! Muito obrigado pela ajuda, seguirei suas orientações.