# Como obter o CEP completo através do GPS do celular

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Estou tentando obter o CEP completo através de minha localização usando o **GPS** de meu celular em **Objective-C**, mas ele retorna apenas 5 dígitos. Utilizei o seguinte trecho de código:

```
NSString *cepcompleto = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", placemark.postalCode, [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"PostCodeExtension"]];
```

Segue o resto do código:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            NSString *cepcompleto = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", placemark.postalCode, [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"PostCodeExtension"]];

            digitoCep = [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"PostCodeExtension"];
            cepEstatico = cepcompleto;

            [vg setCep];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    }];
    [manager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: Cinco digitos? Parece o padrão americano. Realmente eu não sei que objeto é este `placemark.addressDictionary`, poste mais detalhes do código, isto é uma API?

Comment: Talvez as informações adicionais [desta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13433/4337) te ajude.

Comment: Sim é uma API, achei alguns exemplos parecidos com o meu, mas estava ocorrendo o mesmo problema, em certos pontos ele exibia o cep completo.

Answer (score 2):

Seu código está correto. Entretanto o mapeamento de CEPs no Brasil é falho e pode ser que você se depare com valores nulos no caso da key `@"PostCodeExtension"`. Por este motivo, eu considero uma alternativa mais segura utilizar a key `@"FormattedAddressLines"`.

Ao invés de:

```
NSString *cepcompleto = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", placemark.postalCode, [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"PostCodeExtension"]];
```

Tente isso:

```
NSString *cepcompleto = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [placemark.addressDictionary[@"FormattedAddressLines"][3]];
```

Repare que a key `@"FormattedAddressLines"` é um `NSArray` com outros valores como endereço, bairro e outros valores além do CEP que estão formatados de forma similar ao que encontramos no Brasil.